# Next Js Router.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I try to replace using `Router.replace()` I get the following error:

`TypeError: next_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Router.replace is not a function`

[image]

I have tried like this:

`import { Router } from "next/router";`

```
  {isAuth() && (
              <NavItem>
                <Link href="/signup">
                  <NavLink
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                    onClick={() => signout(() => Router.replace(`/signin`))}
                  >
                    SignOut
                  </NavLink>
                </Link>
              </NavItem>
            )}
```

Any Suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) recommend using it as Hook:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function YourComponent(props) {
  const router = useRouter()

  // *** //

 {isAuth() && (
          <NavItem>
            <Link href="/signup">
              <NavLink
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => signout(() => router.replace(`/signin`))}
              >
                SignOut
              </NavLink>
            </Link>
          </NavItem>
        )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nextjs recommend using `useRouter`. You can access `router` object through this hook like this.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <NavLink onClick={() => signOut(() => router.replace('/signin'))}>Signout</NavLink>
  )
}
```