# Hooks inside of utility components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm trying to follow Ben Awad's lireddit tutorial.

He shows how to make a utility file to show any authentication error across the app.

I think things may have changed with the next/router since he made the video. I'm struggling to figure out a way to use the router to redirect inside a hook, inside a component in this way.

I can't put the useRouter hook inside the exchangeError - I think the reason for that is that when I want to use the exchangeError inside other components, the hook is no longer at the top level, but then I can't figure out how to make the exchangeError work without it, or adapt to the udpated version of next/router.

My best attempt (I know I can't use it like this) is below:

```
import { dedupExchange, fetchExchange, createClient, Exchange } from "urql";
import {  pipe, tap } from 'wonka'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


const errorExchange: Exchange = ({ forward }) => (ops$) => {
    // where can i put this
    // const Router = useRouter();

    return pipe(
      forward(ops$),
      tap(({ error }) => {
        if (error?.message.includes("not authenticated")) {
        //   Router.replace("/auth/login");
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

The version Ben published in lireddit is:

```
const errorExchange: Exchange = ({ forward }) => (ops$) => {
  return pipe(
    forward(ops$),
    tap(({ error }) => {
      if (error?.message.includes("not authenticated")) {
        Router.replace("/login");
      }
    })
  );
};
```

The whole utility file is below:

```
import { dedupExchange, fetchExchange, createClient, Exchange } from "urql";
import { cacheExchange } from '@urql/exchange-graphcache'
import { MeDocument, LoginMutation, RegisterMutation, MeQuery, LogoutMutation } from "../generated/graphql"
import { betterUpdateQuery } from '../utils/betterUpdateQuery'
import {  pipe, tap } from 'wonka'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


const errorExchange: Exchange = ({ forward }) => (ops$) => {
    // where can i put this
    // const Router = useRouter();

    return pipe(
      forward(ops$),
      tap(({ error }) => {
        if (error?.message.includes("not authenticated")) {
        //   Router.replace("/auth/login");
        }
      })
    );
  };


export const createUrqlClient = (ssrExchange: any) => (
    {
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
        fetchOptions: {
            credentials: 'include' as const,
        },
        exchanges: [
            dedupExchange,
            cacheExchange({
            updates: {
                Mutation: {
                logout: (_result, args, cache, info) => {
                    betterUpdateQuery<LogoutMutation, MeQuery>(
                    cache,
                    {query: MeDocument},
                    _result,
                    (result, query) => ({me: null})
                    )
                },
                login: (_result, args, cache, info) => {
                    betterUpdateQuery<LoginMutation, MeQuery>(
                    cache,
                    { query: MeDocument },
                    _result,
                    (result, query) => {
                        if (result.login.errors) {
                        return query;
                        } else {
                        return {
                            me: result.login.user,
                        };
                        }
                    }
                    );
                },
                register: (_result, args, cache, info) => {
                    betterUpdateQuery<RegisterMutation, MeQuery>(
                    cache,
                    { query: MeDocument },
                    _result,
                    (result, query) => {
                        if (result.register.errors) {
                        return query;
                        } else {
                        return {
                            me: result.register.user,
                        };
                        }
                    }
                    );
                },
                },
            },
            }),
            errorExchange,
            ssrExchange,
            fetchExchange,
        ],
    } 
)
```

Then, in the create post form, this utility is used as follows:

```
import { withUrqlClient } from "next-urql";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";
import { useCreatePostMutation } from "../generated/graphql";
import { createUrqlClient } from "../utils/createUrqlClient";
import { useIsAuth } from "../utils/useIsAuth";

const CreatePost: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {
  // const router = useRouter();
  // useIsAuth();
  const [, createPost] = useCreatePostMutation();
  return (
    <Layout variant="small">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ title: "", text: "" }}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          const { error } = await createPost({ input: values });
          if (!error) {
            router.push("/");
          }
        }}
      >

export default withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient)(CreatePost);
```

Comment: Use import Router from "next/router"; instead of hook

Comment: That produces errors (replace is not available on Router anymore).  To resolve those, the suggestions are to use the useRouter hook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676995/next-js-router-replace-is-not-a-function

Comment: Can you please show us the code that invokes `errorExchange`?

Comment: I tried look into benawad's code base, saw `errorExchange` is dependency of `createUrqlClient`, but couldn't find where he invokes `createUrqlClient`. Not familiar with the whole stack, I'll need a bit of context to properly understand the problem.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-passport-and-next-connect/pages/profile.js#L37

Comment: I added the form that is wrapped in the utility (not sure if that's correct terminology)

Comment: That is so random @DraganS- yesterday I used this in the way Ben shows, and got errors saying replace isn't available on Router  - which led me down the hooks path. I'm not getting that today. I can't explain the reasons - I literally uncommented the original that produced the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spent some time diving into [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/e969d226999bb0fcb52ecc203b359f3715ff69bf/packages/next/client/router.ts#L125). Conclusion:

```js
import { dedupExchange, fetchExchange, createClient, Exchange } from "urql";
import { pipe, tap } from 'wonka'
import Router from 'next/router'

const errorExchange: Exchange = ({ forward }) => (ops$) => {

    return pipe(
      forward(ops$),
      tap(({ error }) => {
        if (error?.message.includes("not authenticated")) {
          Router.router.replace("/auth/login");  // <-- `Router.router` is the way
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

I have no clue why they decide to expose the API this way. `Router.router` looks really weird to me, but that's the solution.

---

Note on why `useRouter` hook is not an option.

Hook must be called inside an react component instance. But `errorExchange` is meant to be called by `createUrqlClient`, which is in turn called by `withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient)(CreatePost)`.

`withUrlClient` is a decorator, or HOC in react's term, and [so I checked](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/blob/3eaed7ea172e7f7b2cf91ee12af239806e9f8cc2/packages/next-urql/src/with-urql-client.ts#L39) the timing it calls `errorExchange` is just not right for a hook function to step-in, thus an dead end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this. I have no skills in investigating the source of these probelms so I just go down a maze of dead ends. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I spent a solid hour investigating...And I'm baffled these days things got so complicated just to write an app.